iOS Emulator Working in VSCode, But Physical Devices Only Running in Xcode
The iOS emulator runs properly in VSCode for both debugging and running without debugging, but physical iOS devices only run in Xcode.
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: MR96T6686Q
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                        16.4s
Xcode build done.                                           80.4s
You may be prompted to give access to control Xcode. Flutter uses Xcode to run your app. If access is not allowed, you can change this through your Settings > Privacy & Security > Automation.
Xcode is taking longer than expected to start debugging the app. Ensure the project is opened in Xcode.
Error starting debug session in Xcode: Timed out waiting for CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR to update.
Could not run build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app on 00008030-001451981A30802E.
Try launching Xcode and selecting "Product > Run" to fix the problem:
  open ios/Runner.xcworkspace

Installing and launching...                                       139.8s
Error launching application on iPhone.

This error occurs when running the Flutter app on a physical iOS device. I want to be able to debug my Flutter app on my physical iOS device in VSCode.

Did you find a solution to this? I am having the same issue

Still haven't found a solution.
